# Can not override OnInterceptTouchEvent method in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to override OnInterceptTouchEvent method. I am using listview and trying to implement gesture detecor on it but as I appiled click listeners on child view so on fling method  return null. I figured out that this method can solve my problem but I am unable to override in my activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return true;
}
```

If there exist any other approach to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Can you check my answer and see if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

Activity is not a view class, so there is no `OnInterceptTouchEvent` method,
`OnInterceptTouchEvent` is a function of the ViewGroup class that intercepts touch events.

So you could customize the ListView , then override the `OnInterceptTouchEvent` method,like this :

```
class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override it the Java way when you should be using the C# equivalent.

Also, Intercept touch events are a part of the ViewGroup hierarchy and hence unavailable in your activity.

A ViewGroup is basically a class that holds a bunch of widgets together like a View holder.

Try pasting the below in your custom ListView and then use that ListView as your to implement a gesture detector

```
public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
  return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```